# How to show label in certain time using Timer in python kivy?

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, kivy

I'm trying to display some label using kivy framework in specified time with Timer module. Here is what I have and what I want to include into my python kivy:

```
from threading import Timer 
time_var = 2

def time(): 
  print(time_var) 

t = Timer(time_var, time) 
t.start()
```

Here is my python kivy code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.config import Config
from threading import Timer

Config.set("graphics", "resizable", 0)
Config.set("graphics", "width", 400)
Config.set("graphics", "height", 500)

time_var = 2


class myLayout(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.t = Timer(time_var, self.timer)

        layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical",
                           padding=20,
                           spacing=10)

        btn = Button(text="Click")
        btn.bind(on_press=self.t.start())

        self.add_widget(layout)
        layout.add_widget(btn)

    def timer(self, obj):

        popup = Popup(content=Label(text="timer"),
                      size_hint=(None, None),
                      size=(300, 200))

        return popup.open()


class ReminderApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return myLayout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ReminderApp().run()
```

But I cannot figure it out how to make it work. 
Maybe there is a way to make it using kivy modules.. Please help me because I am stuck..

Answer (score 0):

I guess I figured it out.. correct me if I am wrong

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.config import Config
from threading import Timer

Config.set("graphics", "resizable", 0)
Config.set("graphics", "width", 400)
Config.set("graphics", "height", 500)

time_var = 2


class myLayout(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical",
                           padding=20,
                           spacing=10)

        btn = Button(text="Click")

        self.add_widget(layout)
        layout.add_widget(btn)

        btn.bind(on_press=self.timer)

    def popup(self):

        popup = Popup(content=Label(text="timer"),
                      size_hint=(None, None),
                      size=(300, 200))
        popup.open()

    def timer(self, obj):
        timer = Timer(time_var, self.popup)
        timer.start()


class ReminderApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return myLayout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ReminderApp().run()
```